# What tools are used to test an ethereum smart contract app?

Tags: automated-tests, blockchain, ethereum

What testing tools can be used to robustly cover my smart contract dApp from getting hacked?

Selenium, or any other tool?

Answer (score -1):

Testing Techniques that can be used to test a smart contract:

1. Valid Input Test
2. Invalid Input Test
3. Boundary Value Test
4. Gas Limit Test
5. Reentrancy Test
6. Time Dependency Test
7. Event Emission Test
8. Exception Handling Test
9. Deployment and Upgrade Test
10. Access Control Test
11. Integration Test
12. Security Audit

Comment: These are techniques and not tools as asked